# Change bundle install Ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby/Rails, so forgive me if this is a trivial question. Whenever I run `bundle install`, it installs everything in vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8 instead of vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1, which is the version of Ruby I am using. When I run `ruby -v`, I get the correct 1.9.1 version, but bundle install insists on 1.8 for some reason, and this is causing many errors with basic Rails functionality.

How do I instruct bundle to work with 1.9.1 (and preferably remove any trace of Ruby 1.8)?

Thanks!

EDIT: I've done everything [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6235916/288037) answer says, and I get no trace of 1.8

EDIT AGAIN: Well, it's working somehow. Perhaps restarting Bash fixed it. In any case, is there a general solution to forcing `bundle install` to use a particular version of Ruby, lest this happens again or to someone else?

Comment: Depends on your system. What are you using?

Answer (score 5):

For me the problem seemed to be that I had accidentally configured chef to install bundler with the system ruby gem version which put bundler in a system path:

```
/usr/local/bin/bundle
```

This bundle version used
`/usr/bin/gem` (as noted in the comment above) which forced version 1.8

Really I wanted it installed in the `.rbenv` shims location for my user.

To fix the problem I uninstalled bundler while logged in as root which removed it from `/usr/local/bin`.

I had already installed bundler with gem in my desired ruby version for the user, so now when I call `which bundle` I see:

```
/[user_home]/.rbenv/shims/bundle
```

and now when I run `bundle install` the bundle is associated with the current ruby version.

Answer (score 4):

Bundle works with gems. Check that the *gem* command uses the correct version ruby as well : on Ubuntu Linux I had to symlink */usr/bin/gem* to */usr/bin/gem1.9.1*

(The only difference between /usr/bin/gem1.8 and /usr/bin/gem1.9.1 was the first line defining the ruby version to use: `#!/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1` )